# Apache Rewrite problems with a wild card and a question mark

Tags: regex, apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

So my problem is trying to redirect a set of URL's

below

`http://my.domain.com/team+2+name/?section=football`

to

`www.domain.com`

Ive tried so many variants but I've not been able to fully get what im after.

The furthest ive got is

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} my.domain.com/* [NC]
RewriteRule . http://www.domain.com [R=301,NC]
```

but this still leaves the ?section=football in the URL

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} $my\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^team.+?name$ http://www.domain.com? [R=301,L,NC]
```

`?` in the end will strip off any existing query string.

Comment: Just adding a question mark at the end of my existing rule did the business, cheers for point me in the right direction